# Xamarin Forms - The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, timer, xamarin.forms

right now I am trying to work with the Xamarin Forms in combination with the I2C devices and the Raspberry Pi. I programmed in C# and the Raspberry Pi was installed with Windows IoT. And I have encountered a problem about the timer.

What I wanted to do is creating a System.Threading.Timer and reading data from the I2C devices then displaying it on a Label every second, but when I tried to display the data, the error showed that "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. "

The following code is what I tried to do.

```
    public void InitSecondTimer(int interval)
    {
        secTimer = new Timer(interval);
        secTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        secTimer.Start();
        Debug.WriteLine("Secondtimer inited");
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        double voltage = 0;
        InputI2C(ADC0, ref voltage); //Read data from I2C devices
        ai0.Text = voltage.ToString(); //ai0 is a Label
    }
```

So how can I solve the problem? I am very appreciate for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `System.Threading.Thread.Timer`'s Elapsed event is run on a Thread Pool thread, which doesn't own ACD0 (which I assume is the interface for that device). Instead, you should use the [Xamarin Forms Timer](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-timer/):

> #### Threading
>
> Any code run in a timer will run on the main UI Thread. Make sure you don’t block the UI thread or do any intensive calculations. Ensure you move the code to a background thread if appropriate.

```
public void InitSecondTimer(int interval)
{
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds(interval), () =>
    {
        double voltage = 0;
        InputI2C(ADC0, ref voltage); //Read data from I2C devices
        ai0.Text = voltage.ToString(); //ai0 is a Label

        return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
    });

    Debug.WriteLine("Secondtimer inited");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and correct solution, that works well. I am very grateful that you helped me immediately and saved my time! So cool!